# Salesforce lead capture app: Insufficient privileges

Tags: sales-cloud

I wonder, has anyone tried to use Salesforce lead capture on a custom profile?
I managed to get the tab visible, but then I receive the ‘insufficient privileges’ pop-up with no useful info in it.
I’d love to use some help.

The pop-up appears at the moment when the user hits the 'Lead capture' app/tab. So the app is starting, but then I guess it tries to do something, that is forbidden for the user.

I already extended the default permission set with permission to edit Lead capture object, added permission to apex classes, and also turned 'Default on' visibility for the profile itself(actually, no effect, but just to check it out)

Any other thoughts? Works well on Sysadmin profile though...

*UPD* Tried to utilize 'Modify all data'/'Rest/api' pSystem permissions - no luck

Comment: Are you referring to an app on the AppExchange? You'll need to provide more details to ensure we know what feature you are referring to. I found this app that might be what you are referring to: https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3u00000PsCCrEAN&tab=d If that's it, then you need to refer to the Implementation Guide and User Guide at the bottom of the 'More Details' tab, under Resources & Documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was because of the 'Login as' option. So if I checked it by myself I got an error, but the user themself could reach the tab.